# WCF RESTful Calling Issue in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, wcf, visual-studio-2013

I have an ASP.NET application which has been around since the ASMX days.  When I upgraded this project in the past, I was able to utilize a WCF service by extending the System.Web.Services.WebService class and then utilize WebInvoke attributes to allow for RESTful calls to my various methods.  Here is an example:

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://10.23.41.189/", Name = "SEO")]
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class SEO : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    [WebMethod(Description = "Use this Web Method to log into The SEO Panel")]
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        UriTemplate = "Login?User={User}&Pass={Pass}")]
    public string Login(string User, string Pass)
    {
```

That method would then be called without issue by going to http://10.23.41.189/seo.svc/login?User=USER&Pass=PASS

In the old project, I was using a web site project not a web application and now that I have upgraded to Visual Studio 2013, I am using a web application - and that call no longer works.  I literally ported everything over using copy and paste, when I run the WSDL, I see the methods, but all calls come back with a 400 Bad Request error.  Here is my web.config information:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"
  multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
<services>
  <service name="SEO">
    <endpoint address="http://10.23.41.189/SEO.svc" behaviorConfiguration="json" binding="webHttpBinding" name="MainHttpPoint" contract="SEOPlatform.Intranet.SEO"/>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" name="MexEP" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://10.23.41.189/SEO.svc"/>
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
<bindings>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding openTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" useDefaultWebProxy="false">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2048000" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384"/>
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="json">
      <webHttp helpEnabled="false" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="false" defaultBodyStyle="Bare"/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpGetBinding="webHttpBinding" httpGetBindingConfiguration=""/>
      <serviceDebug httpHelpPageEnabled="false" httpsHelpPageEnabled="false" includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
      <useRequestHeadersForMetadataAddress>
        <defaultPorts>
          <add scheme="http" port="80"/>
        </defaultPorts>
      </useRequestHeadersForMetadataAddress>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

I know that I am missing something but I cannot figure it out - does anybody have any ideas?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I swear I should have just waited - I often write questions here and then the related questions always has the answer I need.  This time that did not happen but, as I entered the web.config data, I discovered the issue.  Rather than delete this question, I figured I would post an answer to hopefully help others.

The problem was with the service name:

```
<services>
  <service name="SEO">
```

With a web site project, the rules are lax but a web application requires the proper notation.  All I did was change this to:

```
<services>
  <service name="SEOPlatform.Intranet.SEO">
```

And that fixed the issue.  I also changed the multipleSiteBindingsEnabled to false but if you need that to be true there are great answers already posted elsewhere on this site.